# Term Store Management Tool from Specific Term Set as "root"

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, term-store

I would like to provide the built-in "Term Store Management Tool" to some specific users. But, when the page loads, I want to filter what is shown to those Users. I only want to show some specific "Term Sets" that were created in the "Site Collection" "Group". (Or, it would be ok to show ALL the Term Sets in this particular Site Collection.) Specifically, I want to hide from them the "Groups" that show by default: "People", "Search Dictionaries" and "System".... I was hoping I could simply use a hyperlink to the "termstoremanager.aspx" page and append some type of Query Parameter such as "?FilterGroup=Site Collection" or something like that. (Could it possibly be that easy?)

Does anyone know ANY way I could do this? I want to avoid confusing the users by having all those other Groups show up as options.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations!
Shayne

Comment: I am still looking for a good solution for this. Any hints are much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am performing something very similar to your request.  Since termstoremanager.aspx is located within the Hive15 LAYOUTS directory (`/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx`), you could replace the file with a custom version.

Now depending on the level of access you want to provide these users, you could do as you suggested and write some JS to grab the query string when the page loads, then remove any term store groups that don't match the query.

If you intend to grant the user(s) Contribute permission, you can mark them in each of the Term Sets' Contributor list.  Then use the OOTB SP javascript library to hide the groups from view if they do not have term sets with the current user assigned as a contributor.  Of course, doing it this way would require care to ensure that you don't lock the administrator out, or hinder tagging-specific term sets.